# RecyclerView и NavigationUI

Tags: android

Возникла проблема при использовании NavigationUI. Структура приложения состоит из одного Activity и множества Fragment.
При переходе с одного фрагмента (RuleListFragment) на другой (RuleFragment) и возвращении обратно на первый фрагмент (RuleListFragment) нажатием кнопки Up все данные в RecyclerView исчезают. Для обновления данных RecyclerView использую OnResume (код ниже), не помогает.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:liftOnScroll="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

fragment_recycler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_rule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fragment_rule"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
public class RuleListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RuleAdapter ruleAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateRule();

        return view;
    }

    private void updateRule() {
        RuleLab ruleLab = RuleLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Rule> rules = ruleLab.getRules();

        if (ruleAdapter == null) {
            ruleAdapter = new RuleAdapter(rules);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ruleAdapter);
        } else {
            ruleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class RuleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Rule rule;
        private TextView ruleTitle;

        public RuleHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false));

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ruleTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        }

        public void bind (Rule rule) {
            this.rule = rule;

            ruleTitle.setText(rule.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.ruleFragment);
        }
    }

    private class RuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RuleHolder> {
        private List<Rule> rules;

        public RuleAdapter (List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RuleHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new RuleHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RuleHolder holder, int position) {
            Rule rule = rules.get(position);
            holder.bind(rule);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return rules.size();
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateRule();
    }
}
```

```
public class RuleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rule, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: в одном вопросе должна быть только одна проблема. если у вас несколько проблем - задайте несколько вопросов. если вопросы связаны, укажите ссылки на них

Comment: В NavigationUI  при возвращении назад фрагмент пересоздатся. Вы можете сохранить состояние Recycler view используя ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете Navigation Component, часть AndroidX. В Navigation Component при переходе между фрагментами они пересоздаются заново. Для того, чтобы сохранить состояние фрагментов вы можете использовать другой компонент AndroidX, называемый `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`. Класс наследуемый от `ViewModel` сохраняет своё состояние при при пересоздании фрагментов. Чтобы хранить данные вы можете объявить внутри данного класса поле `MutableLiveData`, которое позволяет изменять состояние и внутри фрагмента, подписываться на изменения этого состояния. Короче, вот пример:

RuleListViewModel.java:

```java
    public class RuleListViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<Rule>> ruleList = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<List<Rule>> getRuleList() {
        return ruleList;
    }

    public void updateRule(List<Rule> newRules) {
        ruleList.setValue(newRules);
    }

}
```

RuleListFragment:

```java
  public class RuleListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RuleAdapter ruleAdapter;

    private RuleListViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RuleListViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateRule();

        // Подписываемся на обновления
        viewModel.getRuleList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), rules -> {
            if(rules != null) {
                if (ruleAdapter == null) {
                    ruleAdapter = new RuleAdapter(rules);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(ruleAdapter);
                } else {
                    ruleAdapter.updateRules(rules);
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void updateRule() {
        RuleLab ruleLab = RuleLab.get(getActivity());
        // Теперь обновляем не сам адаптер, а LivaData, на изменения которой подписан фрагмент
        viewModel.updateRule( ruleLab.getRules());
    }

    private class RuleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Rule rule;
        private TextView ruleTitle;

        public RuleHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false));

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ruleTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        }

        public void bind(Rule rule) {
            this.rule = rule;

            ruleTitle.setText(rule.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.ruleFragment);
        }
    }

    private class RuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RuleHolder> {
        private List<Rule> rules;

        public RuleAdapter(List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        public void updateRules(List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RuleHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new RuleHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RuleHolder holder, int position) {
            Rule rule = rules.get(position);
            holder.bind(rule);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return rules.size();
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Если у вас не изменяются данные списка, тогда всё можно упростить:

```java
public class RuleListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RuleAdapter(RuleLab.get(getActivity())));

        return view;
    }

    class RuleHolder {
        //TODO
    }

    private class RuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RuleHolder> {
        private final List<Rule> rules;

        RuleAdapter(List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RuleHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new RuleHolder(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RuleHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(rules.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return rules.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если я не изменяю данные которые выводит RecyclerView, то возможно использование обычного пересоздания списка, или нежелательно?

Comment: @pie, Тогда зачем updateRule?

Comment: Из книги, но там процесс немного по другому реализован. Не используется Navigation Component, и переход осуществляется через хост Activity. Вообщем в моем случае можно избавиться от updateRule прописав в onCreateView создание адаптера и его присвоение RecyclerView даже в случае изменения данных, которые повлияют на отображаемый список (ruleTitle например). Я прав?

Comment: @pie, Не совсем вас понимаю. Я обновил пример для случая когда `List<Rule> rules` не меняется. Если список  `List<Rule>` меняется, то адаптер должен как-то об этом узнать, тогда используйте первый подход. Если данные в списка не меняются, используйте второй подход.

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере не происходит изменение Adapter поэтому `ruleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` не работает. Так же некорректно работает onResume. Поэтому убираем onResume, и условие в updateRule.